# CORS error on Chrome but works in IE

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, cors, sharepoint-online, jira-rest-api

I have created a form that would enable users to raise JIRA tickets from an html form. i have asked the admin to add the origin (sharepoint online site, the form is hosted) to the whitelist of JIRA as a wildard expression with format https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/*.

it now works in IE but i still get errors in chroe:

> jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://jira.xxx.xx/rest/api/2/issue/. Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 403.

in Edge i get this error:

> HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is
>   refusing to fulfill it.

One thing i have noticed is that when i run it on IE, after clicking submit. i am presented with a pop screen to log onto my JIRA credentials. this doesnt happen to Chrome or Edge. can you please let me know what i am missing here?

This is my ajax call:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jira.xxxx.com/rest/api/2/issue/',
    type: "POST",
    data: parameters,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'basic: '+make_base_auth(username, password));
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://jira.xxxx.com');
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-Atlassian-Token', 'nocheck');
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL');
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If');
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'DAV, content-length, Allow');
    },
    error: function (errmsg) {
        console.log('error ocured:' + errmsg.statusText);
    },
    success: function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the Access-Control headers you are adding are *response headers*.  Sending them in the request is meaningless.  CORS does have a couple request headers, but they are sent by the browser.  Your requests shouldn't send them.  If the *server* is properly configured for cross-origin requests, it will set these headers when appropriate in the responses it returns.

Chrome is telling you that the CORS preflight request doesn't have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  The preflight request is an OPTIONS request that is sent to ask the server if it will be allowed to make a request.  If the server sends back the right headers (currently it isn't) then the browser knows it can make the actual POST request.  You aren't getting past the preflight request.

There is nothing wrong with your request for a cross-origin perspective (other than the extraneous headers already mentioned).  Assuming everything else is correct, the problem is with the server running the API.  Whoever controls that server will need to configure it to properly respond to CORS preflight requests.

My best guess is that the API is configured to respond to actual requests, but not preflight requests.  And, I'm guessing that IE incorrectly treats the request as a "simple request" which doesn't require a preflight request.  That could explain why it works in IE, but not Chrome.  But, I can only guess without more information.

Comment: Hi @Jason, would you happen to know what to configure in the server? because it's a JIRA application im not sure what configurations to change and i would have to see if i have the necessary permissions. Thank you for you answer

Comment: I have never used the JIRA API, so I don't know it's configuration options.  I don't even know if there are configuration options that allow for this.  I can tell you that it must respond to OPTIONS requests with the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.